# Standalone rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I was developing a simple application in symfony php. What I liked about it was that it was totally standalone and portable. Everything was installed and stored in the project directory. You can just copy the whole project directory to a different machine supporting php and it works.

I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve the same effect with ruby on rails - to create an application and no longer worry about the **rails version** and the **gems** provided by a host.

So, is it possible? And if it is than how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in Rails 3 you achieve this via a [Gemfile](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) + [bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

The Gemfile contains your list of required gems & their versions, and bundler allows you to [vendor those gems in a path within your app](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/).